# How to load integration test data

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa

We've a Java-Tomcat project, using Spring, JPA, with maven build, JUnit for unit tests and TestNG for integration tests.

Some integration tests will require a database, so a new DB is created each time `mvn verify` is run. The problem is now to populate it to have test data.

Should I look into [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/), persist the objects myself using JPA, or another way?

How to load test data in the DB, each time integration tests are run to have a stable testing environment?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `dbunit` with an in memory database. It's helpful to load the specific test datasets, to run the tests, to verify the database contents after each test and to clean up the database after the test is run.

The "pros" of `dbunit` would be that it allows you to control the state of the database before and after each test. The "cons" is that you will work with test datasets in a custom xml format, not SQL. You can export from sql to this custom xml format, but you will still need occasionally to manually edit the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I take a copy of live database and make tests transactional so they are rolled back each time.

Comment: As teh live data is changeable, your test cases might not then be repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

We use Dbunit.
We load test data within junit in a @BeforeClass method.
And delete/clean data in a @BeforeClass and a @AfterClass method.

Comment: That works only if all your integration tests need the same test data.

Comment: @Raedwald yes, they need the same test data because it's the same automated test.Sometimes we have to change the XML to adapt change in data model.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is now to populate it to have test data

As each integration test might need to have different test data, I think that should be done as part of the set-up phase of each of the integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

There are two patterns to consider Fresh Fixture and Shared Fixture. The first one provides better tests isolation as it is about recreating test data for each test case, i.e. assuring a clean state. The later one introduces the risk of tests coupling but is faster as reuses the same instances of test data across many tests. Both are described in details in Meszaros: *xUnit Test Patterns*.

Regardless of the choice, it may be worth to consider the random data driven approach designed on top of the test-arranger: [How to organize tests with Test Arranger](https://github.com/ocadotechnology/test-arranger#how-to-organize-tests-with-test-arranger). According to my knowledge, it's the cheapest approach with regard to maintenance costs and the required amount of code.